# Table header issue

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I add a `UISearchBar` to a `UITavleView` (as the table header), it allows the user to hide that search bar by scrolling it out of the screen, and it also stays that way. 
How can I do that with a custom view set as the table header? By default it doesn't work, it bounces back into the screen.
I've tried setting the content offset of the table view, but that hides the header only until the first scroll. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for `tableHeaderView` property of `UITableView`?

Comment: Yes, if you add the `searchBar` to it (e.g. in Story Board) you can hide it by scrolling it out

Comment: it's working as intended. What's the problem?

Comment: I know, but how can you do this with a custom header. Make it stay out of the screen if you scroll up and the table isn't full?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `headerView` with your own custom view.

```
UIView * headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 80.0)];

[headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:headerView];
```